# "The instance of entity type cannot be tracked.." Error while writing unit test with xUnit. I don't encounter this error except for unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I completed my API project and edited the error I mentioned in the application using `AsNoTracking`. However, while typing the test of my Update controller, test explorer gives the error:

> "The instance of entity type cannot be tracked..".

How can I solve this problem.

Here is my Update repository : (it works flawlessly)

```
public override void Update(Book entity)
    {
        var result = _context.Books.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProductId == entity.ProductId);

        if (result == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Güncellemek istediğiniz kitap bulunamadı.");

        base.Update(entity);
        base.Save();
    }
```

Here is my `UpdateOperation` test class :

```
 private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public UpdateOperationTests()
    {

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
       .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking).Options;

        _context = new ApplicationDbContext(options);

        _context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void UpdateBook()
    {
        /* Arrange */

        var newBook = BookMockData.UpdateBook();
        _context.Books.AddRange(BookMockData.GetBooks());
        _context.SaveChanges();

        var sut = new BookRepository(_context);

        /* Assert & Act */
        
        FluentActions.Invoking(() => sut.Update(newBook)).Should().NotThrow();
    }
```

And Here is my error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you use AsNoTracking() in your repository's Update method, it means that the entity is not being tracked by the DbContext, and when you try to update it, Entity Framework Core doesn't know about its changes.

In your test, when you call the Update method, it modifies the entity, but since it's not being tracked, EF Core doesn't detect the changes, and when you later try to save changes, it doesn't see any modifications and nothing gets persisted.

Instead of using AsNoTracking(), you can use the _context.Attach(entity)

```
public override void Update(Book entity)
{
    var result = _context.Books.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProductId == entity.ProductId);

    if (result == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Güncellemek istediğiniz kitap bulunamadı.");

    _context.Attach(entity);
    _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

    base.Save();
}
```